# In Excel, how do I extract last four letters of a ten letter string?

Tags: excel, extract, excel-formula

For example, if I have

```
ABS YUR YUAO   
HFH IWO OQNX  
YQO PQM QUCC
```

How do I extract the last four letters in another column?

Comment: If any answer from the given answers helps you then you should accept it by clicking on √ button below the upvote-downvote button.

Answer (score 52):

No need to use a macro. Supposing your first string is in A1.

```
=RIGHT(A1, 4)
```

Drag this down and you will get your four last characters.

Edit: To be sure, if you ever have sequences like 'ABC DEF' and want the last four LETTERS and not CHARACTERS you might want to use trimspaces()

```
=RIGHT(TRIMSPACES(A1), 4)
```

Edit: As per brettdj's suggestion, you may want to check that your string is actually 4-character long or more:

```
=IF(TRIMSPACES(A1)>=4, RIGHT(TRIMSPACES(A1), 4), TRIMSPACES(A1))
```

Comment: Suggest adding a check for the string being at least four characters long before looking to extract the last four chars.

Comment: Note that if only one argument is specified, only the last character is returned, e.g. `=RIGHT("ABS YUR YUAO")` returns `O`